# Adding and subtracting height in Jquery BUGGING

Tags: jquery, html, css, height

Im adding/subtracting height on a div element, with an ul inside it. The add/subtract events fire upon click on other unrelated divs in the document.

Now.. the problem occurs when user SPAMfires the event. This, **for some unknown reason**, results in, the div on which we add/subtract height, to either increase or lower it's base height.

*Note - I'm adding and subtracting the exact same amount, and therefore, the base height of the div in question, should not either increase or lower.*

I apologize for the following fiddle's extensive code, but i've had to cp the sourcecode, seeing as I just couldn't achieve the same bug, recreating the example.

http://jsfiddle.net/st5dzcnc/

In the js section, refer to the three $(function)'s.
In the result section, i've clearly marked the three elements that will trigger the event, in orange and stated it "SPAMCLICK HERE".

Doing the forementioned will result in the blue div below, either increasing or lowering it's base height - WHICH I need to avoid happening.

```
 <div>refer to jsf</div>
```

I've tried doing everything i could think of to fix this, but nothing has worked, I'm at a complete standstill of what to do and really need help.

//Edit:
The middle ORANGE button, will definetely achieve the bug, not sure as to the two other in jsf. In sourcecode all three buttons achieve the bug though!

For everyone to see, i've uploaded the bug to youtube.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rBAfjuHqpWY&feature=youtu.be&hd=1

Comment: The height gets set differently based on which spamclick I clicked, is this normal? If so then I don't see any height change issues. You can always add a class or a flag to stop the spam clicking from happening which i think is a better behaviour overall

Comment: Spamclick the middle button. It will after a while have either increased or lowered the base height of the blue div.

Comment: I get 9.29832 and 16.4182 after 2 clicks and it stays at those values. These number change if you resize the height. Why is there so many handlers for the same element?

Comment: Try doing it without inspecting. For some reason i get the same result as you with the inspection pane open. Doing if without will visibly increase the size, not even any need for inspection. And btw, when i say spam - I mean click it atleast around 20 times in a row.

Comment: I don't see any difference

Comment: I made a counter to show the height, and the 2 numbers are not changing http://jsfiddle.net/st5dzcnc/1/

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rBAfjuHqpWY&feature=youtu.be&hd=1

Comment: Notice how the base height increases from the original height.

Comment: But that's the case when you click on it 2 times, because the height first set is different. As I mentioned in my previous comment, if you switch click items the height will change once then stabilize. The height for that div is set to 9.5vh by css and when you click on any of the items, it changes

Comment: The requirement for code within the question when including a jsfiddle is there for a reason.  You should not enter fake/irrelevant code to bypass the rule.

Comment: Hmm, Huangism. I don't understand what you're getting at tbh. In my mind, clicking the same button twice in a row would return it to the base height seeing as im adding/subtracting the exact same value.

Comment: James, which part of the 50 page code would you want me to include?

Comment: @RasmusHjorthLüdeking Oh I see what you mean, 9.5vh +/- 7.2vh should yield the 9,5 at the end, is that what you mean? Perhaps the calculation is done in different units and then converting it back made the difference

Comment: Exactly. Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: If that indeed is the issue then maybe doing the +/- with finite units will solve it. Maybe try using % and see if that works. I have simplified your code down here http://jsfiddle.net/st5dzcnc/2/

Comment: Thank you for your help so far Huang! I will get cracking tommorow, and let you know!

Comment: Hmm, took at look at your two options Huang. Neither of them worked not finite numbers and not percentage. Any other ideas? Or am i gonna have to block the user from spamming the event?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who might experience the same problem, i've isolated the problem and fixed it.

The problem was the scroller plugin I had put on top. The soucecode for the plugin was all in px, meanwhilst the event script was in vh, which resulted in the calculations malfunctioning.

By rewriting the sourcecode to all vh, the problem was fixed!